# Is it possible to facilitate MetaMask Authentication via backend api calls?

Tags: metamask, ethers.js

Currently, transactions are being authenticated by MetaMask when we interact with their browser extension. However, is it possible to execute the same user steps via backend calls instead as I thinking of wrapping authentication steps within our api?

Thank you very much

Comment: Metamask holds the user's private key and sign transaction for them. You can do on backend if your backend hold your user's wallets private key.

Answer (score 0):

Sure! The issue is, the gas for the transactions needs to be paid for the private key from your backend code. You can transact tokens in behalf of others through `setAllowance()`. There's some limitations though.